# How can we get the iPhone screen to stay active, instead of going into the power saving mode?

Tags: iphone, screen, power-saving

I am working on a simple game that requires `UIAccelerometer` without any screen tapping interaction. In the default mode, the screen goes into a power saving mode periodically. How can I make the screen to stay active throughout the entire time what the app is active?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES` to prevent the iPhone to go to sleep-mode.

Comment: But be careful when using this, make sure you allow idling in situations where the game is kind of idling - e.g. main-menu, pause mode, ... - to prevent excessive battery draining and possible rejection.

Comment: thanks for the heads up! I will pay attention to these points.